# How do I set custom buttons when using protoApp instead of newtApplication?

Tags: newtonscript

I'm developing a Newton OS app in NewtonScript and the `protoApp` proto fits the application type better than the `newtApplication` proto (i.e. NewtApp). `protoApp` provides the title & status bar with close box, but how do I insert custom buttons in the status bar (since it only shows the clock)?

Comment: What kind of buttons do you have in mind? Something along the lines of Routing and Action buttons, or something customized?

Comment: In this case, I was just adding the info button, but my only other plans at the moment are for the routing button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.systems.newton.newtontalk/23047) on [NewtonTalk](http://www.newtontalk.net/), where [Paul Guyot](http://www.kallisys.com/) says:

> You don't need to use protoApp. You can use protoFloater instead. You 
>   can then add a nicer NewtonOS 2.x-like status bar to replace the ugly 
>   clock/battery picker of protoApp and put the close box on this bar. 
>   The trick is to steal the bar from the NewtApp framework, i.e. to use 
>   newtStatusBarNoClose. I did this for several projects, it's probably 
>   documented as is in the doc (the fact that you can use 
>   newtStatusBar[NoClose] instead of protoStatusBar) and you can take 
>   advantage of the buttons handling code (to align them automatically 
>   on the left and on the right).

It turns out the suggestion of using `newtStatusBar` instead of `protoStatus` *is* documented in the Newton Programmer's Guide (2.0) on page 7-19:

> **Note**
>   The new status bar protos newtStatusBarNoClose and 
>   newtStatusBar, are the preferred way to add a status bar to 
>   your applications. These protos, which are described in 
>   “NewtApp Applications” (page 4-1), simplify adding buttons and 
>   automate hiding the close box when your application is moved 
>   into the background.

And, Paul's suggestion of using `protoFloater` instead of `protoApp` was dead-on, although, I actually ended up using `protoDragger`. I had to manually add the `protoTitle` & `protoStatusBar`:

```
mainView := {
    _proto: protoDragger,
    viewflags: vApplication + vVisible + vClickable,
    appSymbol: kAppSymbol,
    viewJustify: vjParentFullH + vjParentFullV,
    viewBounds: {left: 16, top: 16, right: -16, bottom: -16},
    stepChildren: [
        {
            _proto: protoTitle,
            title: kAppTitle
        },
        {
            _proto: newtStatusBar,
            menuLeftButtons: [],
            menuRightButtons: []
        },
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The Newton proto and view framework is pretty flexible, so while it is nice to have something like NewtApp do a lot of magic behind the scenes, I found it often works as well to just directly code the layout as needed. In the example below, I just create a button as a child view of the app, and move it to the right spot. I don't thing we have to expect a lot of changes to the protos anymore, so the pixel values can be fixed as such :)

```
mainView := {
    _proto: protoApp,
    title: "App Title",
    appSymbol: 'appSymbol,

    stepChildren: [
        {
            _proto: protoTextButton,
            text: "Custom",
            viewJustify: vjParentRightH + vjParentBottomV + vjCenterH,
            viewBounds: {left: -70, top: -16, right: -26, bottom: -3}
        },
    ],

    viewJustify: vjParentFullH + vjParentFullV,
    viewBounds: {left: 16, top: 16, right: -16, bottom: -16},
};
```

Comment: Very true, there hasn't been any drift in protos for a while now. :)